# How can I proactively close a synchronous tungstenite websocket connection?

Tags: rust, websocket, synchronization

I am trying to write a websocket client to connect the server.

I put the websocket connection to another thread to read, then I'd like to close the connection from the main thread, but couldn't figure out a way to do it because the `arc_ws_stream.lock()` in the main thread will be blocked forever (locked by the mutex in the spawned thread).

Here are the dependencies in Cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
tungstenite = "0.21.0"
url = "2.5.0"
native-tls = "0.2.11"
websocket = "0.27.0"
```

Here is the main.rs

```
#![allow(unused_imports)]
use std::{net::ToSocketAddrs, error, fmt::format, net, sync::{Arc, Mutex}, thread::{self, sleep}, time::Duration};
use tungstenite::{protocol::CloseFrame, WebSocket, Message, Error};
use url::Url;
use native_tls::TlsConnector;
use websocket::{result::WebSocketError, ClientBuilder, OwnedMessage};

fn main()  {
    connect_to_websocket("wss://127.0.0.1:7878/ws", String::from("login message"));
}

fn connect_to_websocket(uri: &str, login_msg: String){
  let ws_url = Url::parse(uri).unwrap();

  // Create a TLS connector that ignores invalid certificates
  let tls_connector = TlsConnector::builder().danger_accept_invalid_certs(true).build().unwrap();

  // Establish a TCP connection, then wrap the TCP stream with TLS and connect to the server
  let remote_addr = format!("{}:{}", ws_url.host().unwrap(), ws_url.port().unwrap());
  let tcp_stream = std::net::TcpStream::connect(remote_addr.clone()).unwrap();
  let tls_stream = tls_connector.connect(remote_addr.as_str(), tcp_stream).unwrap();
  let (mut raw_ws_stream, _) = tungstenite::client(uri, tls_stream).unwrap();

  raw_ws_stream.send(Message::Text(login_msg)).unwrap();

  let arc_ws_stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(raw_ws_stream));
  let thread_ws_stream = arc_ws_stream.clone();
  let ws_recv_thread = thread::spawn(move ||{
    loop{
      let msg = thread_ws_stream.lock().unwrap().read();
      if !process_ws_msg(msg) { 
        break;
      }
    }
  });  

  sleep(Duration::from_millis(5_000));
  let _ = arc_ws_stream.lock().unwrap().close(None);  //this line will be blocked forever
  let _ = ws_recv_thread.join();  
}

fn process_ws_msg(msg: Result<Message, Error>)->bool {
    match msg{
        Ok(msg) => {
          match msg {
            Message::Text(msg) => {
                println!("WS received message: {}", msg);
            },
            Message::Close(cls_msg) => {
              match cls_msg{
                Some(cls_frame) =>{
                  println!("WS session closed message, close frame = {}", cls_frame);
                }
                None =>{
                  println!("WS session closed message, no close frame");
                }
              }
              return  false;
            },
            _ => {}
          }
        },
        Err(err) =>{
          println!("WS session error: {}", err);
          return false;
        }
    }
    true
}
```

I tried to use async solution but couldn't solve the invalid SSL certificate issue.

Comment: I don't know what async has to do with TLS not working. Closing the connection while reading will be far easier to do with async because you can just abort the read task.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes it sounds pretty easy but 
I just couldn't make it happen. Could you please share some runable code? Thanks.

Comment: Instead you should share the async code you couldn't get working so we can see how to fix it.

Comment: @cdhowie To be honest, I don't think you can help then, either you know how to do it but you don't have time, or you don't know how to. Because the question is simple and clear enough.

Comment: You are welcome to make whatever incorrect assumptions about me you would like to. However, this does not change the fact that I cannot magically determine what issue you ran into with TLS without seeing your code.